# System preferences panel (install)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbundle, mac-app-store

I am about to submit my app to Mac App Store. My client wants the settings to reside in "System Preferences" panel. I created the bundle, but I have 3 questions:

1. Is having settings in System Preferences allowed in Mac App Store?
2. How can I install this bundle when the application is first run?
3. Do I send the source code of both the bundle and application to apple?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your application has no GUI of its own and affects the entire system, its preferences should definitely *not* go into System Preferences. Unlike iOS, Mac apps should contain their own preference-setting interface. The [Preference Pane Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/PreferencePanes.html) has [this to say about System Preferences](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Concepts/Application.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000702-104804):

> System Preferences is the standard
>   location for presenting system-level
>   preferences. The preference panes
>   shipped with Mac OS X include panes
>   affecting hardware (such as the Sound,
>   Mouse, and Display panes), software
>   integrated into the system (such as
>   the Dock and Screen Saver panes), and
>   behavior applicable to every
>   application (such as the International
>   and General panes).
>
> When your preferences apply to the
>   system or to the user’s environment as
>   a whole, make the preference pane
>   available to System Preferences. This
>   may include panes for the following
>   situations:
>
> - additional input devices such as tablets, multi-function mice, and
>     microphones
> - configurable internal hardware such as processor upgrade cards
> - light-weight faceless server applications such as a file server
> - system-wide utilities such as keyboard macros
>
> Unless your preference pane clearly
>   belongs in System Preferences, use a
>   custom preference application instead.

If you *were* to put your application's settings into the System Preferences, you would create a Preference Pane, as described in the above-linked guide (it sounds like you may have already done this?). In order to make it easy for your users to install both the app and an item into /Library, you will probably want to use [Package Maker](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), which will create an installer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just found out and it is not allowed (#2.15 in Mac app store review guidelines)