# Sandbox and preference pane

Tags: cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I've written an application that handle preferences stored in a group container. This preferences file is used by this application and by a daemon. I would like to convert the application into a preference pane located in the system preferences. But when I create the project in Xcode, there are no capabilities options in the target of the project.

The System Preferences is the main application but is there a way to make the preference pane run in a sandbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [System preferences panel (install)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808768/system-preferences-panel-install)

If you're sandboxing the App to be distributed in Mac App Store, you're out of luck as Preference Panes aren't allowed (Section 2.15 of the guideline)

Comment: Yes, you're right. system preferences panes are not allowed in a sandbox environment. Thanks.

Comment: @Lionel_A would you be so kind to accept the answer?

Comment: I accept the answer of course. I've posted a comment about your answer on november 25 and I've said that you were right.

Comment: @Lionel_A there is the possibility to mark the question as solved by clicking the checkmark below the arrow and the number left to my answer.